# send_keys issue in Python

Tags: python, sendkeys

I would like to put text value in textbox input type="text" and input type="password".

```
        <div class="inner">

        <div id="dispErrorMsgArea"></div>

        <p>ご登録いただいているユーザーIDとパスワードを入力してください。</p>
        <table class="table table-form">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ユーザーID
                    </th>
                    <td class="form-wrap form-vp">
                        <input type="text" name="dispuserId" id="dispuserId" value="" maxLength="50" class="form-text w200" />
                        <p><em>半角英数字・記号6～50文字で入力してください。</em></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        パスワード
                    </th>
                    <td class="form-wrap form-vp form-vp-pw">
                        <input type="password" name="disppassword" id="disppassword" value="" maxLength="20" class="form-text w200" />
                        <p><em>半角英数字6～20文字で入力してください。</em></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I could get name element for each textbox correctly using below code but I could not put text.

```
for div_table_element in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div > table'):

for tbody_tr_element in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tbody > tr'):
    
    td_element = tbody_tr_element.find_element_by_tag_name('td')
    print(td_element.find_element_by_tag_name('input[name]').is_selected())
    input_element = td_element.find_element_by_tag_name('input[name]')
    input_element.send_keys('TestTest')
    print(input_element.get_attribute('name'))
```

and will get below result.

False
dispuserId
False
disppassword

Is there any way to resolve the issue?

Comment: If you do `td_element.find_element_by_tag_name('input[name]').click()` first and then do `print(td_element.find_element_by_tag_name('input[name]').is_selected())`. Do you get `True`?

Comment: @Drejc, thank you for your suggestion. I chanced my code as you advice, but I got None from `td_element.find_element_by_tag_name('input[name]').click()` ...